# File creation in SD card not working

Tags: android

I am trying to create a file and store it in SD Card to be used as an input for some processing for an apps.
After searching for a while, I got this code which can create a file in SD card.But after running this,I couldn't see any file created in my SD card. Can anyone please help me what I am missing here.

```
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(FileDescriptor.err));

try {
    File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    if (root.canWrite()) {
    File perffile = new File(root, "samplefile.txt");
    FileWriter perfwriter = new FileWriter(perffile, true);
    out = new BufferedWriter(perfwriter);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "-Could not write file " + e.getMessage());
    return; 
}
```

Comment: You haven't actually written something to the file. Not sure with the internals of FileWriter, but I don't think that this file will be created without writing something to it...

Comment: Well I made a little desktop java program out of this and on linux I can confirm that it does create the file simply with this code.

Comment: Did you ask for the permission in your manifest?

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: Yes, I did ask for permission you mentioned above in manifest file. I am working on Windows 7.

Comment: I am getting this message : ActivityManager(525): Process com.example.samplejni (pid 8016) has died.

Comment: Well if 'root.canWrite()' returns false, this code will do nothing.  I would add else clause with a log message, th check this.

Comment: I tried that.It is executing the if condition only.

Comment: One Naive question. Do I need SD card on the PC on which I am running the eclipse or my android device i.e Nexus 4 on which I am running my apps.

Comment: According to the source (http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/os/Environment.java#Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29), getExternalStorageDirectory is implemented to return whatever is set as "external storage" in the device environment.

Comment: I am running it on Nexus 4 and it doesn't have support for SD card. Could that be a problem ? Should I be using the main memory instead rather than External one ? Any link or code that could be helpful

Comment: Also, from the code I just looked at, I think you need to close the `out` as in `out.Close()`, I think...

Answer (score -1):

If you want to add a file or folder or move application into your SD Card just do the following:

steps:

1) Open your Android application's source code file with a text or programming editor.

2) Browse to the location in the source code where you wish to call the function that writes a file to the device's external storage.

3) Insert this single line of code to check for the SD card:

```
File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

4) Insert these lines of code to set the directory and file name:

```
File dir = new File (sdcard.getAbsolutePath() + "/folder1/folder2");
dir.mkdirs();
File file = new File(dir, "example_file");

// The mkdirs funtion will create the directory folder for you, use it only you want to create a new one.
```

5) Replace "/folder1/folder2" in the above code with the actual path where you intend to save the file. This should be a location in which you normally save your application files. Also, change the "example_file" value to the actual file name you wish to use.

6) Insert the following line of code to output the file to the SD card:

```
FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(file);
Finally step 7:
```

Save the file, then compile it and test the application using the Android emulator software or the device.

This will works!!! ;-)

Comment: A case of self plagiarism: This answer is the exact same as [user3612615's answer to *Move to SD card on Android*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7135441/move-to-sd-card-on-android/23521747#23521747) ([first revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/23521747/1)).