# How to make sd card in eclipse android first time

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am new in android. I have no idea about sd card.

How do we create sd card in android eclipse?

Comment: To clarify, what is being discussed here is an *image* file used as a *virtual* sd card with the emulator.

Comment: Check this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788451/how-to-install-sd-card-on-android-emulator-1-6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create an sd card when you create an AVD(Android virtual device).

Go to Window -> Android Virtual Device Manager. Then click on new.[image]

Comment: thanks man. but using this method how we access sd card (means through which name). how to set the name of sd card..

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  It's one of the options in the wizard when you create a new AVD.  You can specify the memory size for both internal and SD.